# File Browser not as part of the Kendo UI Editor

Tags: kendo-ui

I am looking for a way to get stand alone [File Browser](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/imagebrowser) control just like in the Kendo UI Editor.

The presented solution in their [forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/file-manager-2caeaccf98d2) uses Image Browser which has file type restrictions and thumbnails that we do not need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for file browser not as part of the Kendo UI Rich Text Editor control, not image browser, you can accomplish this (although it is not officially supported by Telerik/Progress).

You can use:

> kendoFileBrowser

```
<div class="file-borwser-js"></div>


$(".file-borwser-js").kendoFileBrowser({
    "messages":
{
    "deleteFile": "Сигурни ли сте че искате да изтриете \"{0}\"?",
    "directoryNotFound": "Директория с посоченото име не бе открита.",
    "emptyFolder": "Празна папка",
    "invalidFileType": "Избраният файл \"{0}\" не е валиден. Поддържаните файлови формати са {1}.",
    "orderBy": "Подреди по:",
    "orderBySize": "Големина",
    "orderByName": "Име",
    "overwriteFile": "Файл с име \"{0}\" вече съществува в тази папка. Искате ли да го презапишете?",
    "uploadFile": "Качи файл",
    "dropFilesHere": "преместете с мишката файлове тук за да ги качите",
    "search": "Търси"
},
    "transport":
    {
        "type": "filebrowser-aspnetmvc",
        "read": { "url": "/FileBrowser/Read" },
        "uploadUrl": "/FileBrowser/Upload",
        "destroy": { "url": "/FileBrowser/Destroy" },
        "create": { "url": "/FileBrowser/Create" },
        "fileUrl": "/FileBrowser/File?path={0}"
    }
});
```

The way I got this is from the inline Javascript that is downloaded with the Kendo Editor. And copied the "fileBrowser" element. Then I used this element as parameter of `kendoFileBrowser()`

```
    jQuery(function(){jQuery("#_0__Content").kendoEditor({"tools":[{"name":"bold"},{"name":"italic"},{"name":"underline"},{"name":"strikethrough"},{"name":"justifyLeft"},{"name":"justifyCenter"},{"name":"justifyRight"},{"name":"justifyFull"},{"name":"insertUnorderedList"},{"name":"insertOrderedList"},{"name":"outdent"},{"name":"indent"},{"name":"createLink"},{"name":"unlink"},{"name":"insertImage"},{"name":"insertFile"},{"name":"subscript"},{"name":"superscript"},{"name":"createTable"},{"name":"addColumnLeft"},{"name":"addColumnRight"},{"name":"addRowAbove"},{"name":"addRowBelow"},{"name":"deleteRow"},{"name":"deleteColumn"},{"name":"viewHtml"},{"name":"formatting"},{"name":"cleanFormatting"},{"name":"fontName"},{"name":"fontSize"},{"name":"foreColor"},{"name":"backColor"}],"messages":{"bold":"Получер","italic":"Курсив","underline":"Подчертай","strikethrough":"Зачертай","superscript":"Горен индекс","subscript":"Долен индекс","justifyCenter":"Центрирай","justifyLeft":"Подравни отляво","justifyRight":"Подравни отдясно","justifyFull":"Подравни","insertOrderedList":"Вмъкни номериран списък","insertUnorderedList":"Вмъкни списък","indent":"Добави отстъп","outdent":"Премахни отстъп","createLink":"Направи препратка","unlink":"Премахни препратка","insertImage":"Вмъкни картина","insertFile":"Вмъкни файл","insertHtml":"Вмъкни HTML","fontName":"Шрифт","fontNameInherit":"(наследен шрифт)","fontSize":"Размер на шрифта","fontSizeInherit":"(наследен размер)","formatBlock":"Избери формат","styles":"Стилове","backColor":"Цвят на фона","foreColor":"Цвят","viewHtml":"Виж HTML-а","dialogUpdate":"Обнови","createTable":"Създай таблица"},"imageBrowser":{"messages":{"deleteFile":"Сигурни ли сте че искате да изтриете \"{0}\"?","directoryNotFound":"Директория с посоченото име не бе открита.","emptyFolder":"Празна папка","invalidFileType":"Избраният файл \"{0}\" не е валиден. Поддържаните файлови формати са {1}.","orderBy":"Подреди по:","orderBySize":"Големина","orderByName":"Име","overwriteFile":"Файл с име \"{0}\" вече съществува в тази папка. Искате ли да го презапишете?","uploadFile":"Качи файл","dropFilesHere":"преместете с мишката файлове тук за да ги качите","search":"Търси"},"transport":{"read":{"url":"/ImageBrowser/Read"},"type":"imagebrowser-aspnetmvc","thumbnailUrl":"/ImageBrowser/Thumbnail","uploadUrl":"/ImageBrowser/Upload","destroy":{"url":"/ImageBrowser/Destroy"},"create":{"url":"/ImageBrowser/Create"},"imageUrl":"/ImageBrowser/Image?path={0}"}},"fileBrowser":{"messages":{"deleteFile":"Сигурни ли сте че искате да изтриете \"{0}\"?","directoryNotFound":"Директория с посоченото име не бе открита.","emptyFolder":"Празна папка","invalidFileType":"Избраният файл \"{0}\" не е валиден. Поддържаните файлови формати са {1}.","orderBy":"Подреди по:","orderBySize":"Големина","orderByName":"Име","overwriteFile":"Файл с име \"{0}\" вече съществува в тази папка. Искате ли да го презапишете?","uploadFile":"Качи файл","dropFilesHere":"преместете с мишката файлове тук за да ги качите","search":"Търси"},"transport":{"read":{"url":"/FileBrowser/Read"},"type":"filebrowser-aspnetmvc","uploadUrl":"/FileBrowser/Upload","destroy":{"url":"/FileBrowser/Destroy"},"create":{"url":"/FileBrowser/Create"},"fileUrl":"/FileBrowser/File?path={0}"}}});});
```

Tested on Kendo UI: 2015.1.318

I have tried to post it on their [forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/file-manager-2caeaccf98d2) as an answer, but apparently you have to be super premium to do so and I am posting it here.

Comment: I got this to work even with the newest version of Kendo.  The "type" property in the transport object is the key to making it work correctly, by the way.  Can't forget that one!